# "You must provide a hash." error when using API to download data (in R)

Tags: r, api, httr

I would like to extract the data from MARVEL DEVELOPER by API code and analyze it (using R).

I got the following url from MARVEL website: http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/characters?apikey=f389fcb49ad574e10ca570867f4bfa43

I used httr package to collect the data:

```
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
> url <- GET("http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/characters?orderBy=name&limit=100&apikey=f389fcb49ad574e10ca570867f4bfa43")
> content(url)
$code
[1] "MissingParameter"

$message
[1] "You must provide a hash."
```

I want to extract all this data to R. What should I do/read?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a hash when you signed up? Obviously you should pass it on to your request http://developer.marvel.com/documentation/generalinfo

Answer (score 15):

You have to provide ts (timestamp) and hash parameter. Hash is (according to [documentation](https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization)) = md5(ts+privateKey+publicKey)

You can compute md5 with:

```
library(digest)
hash <- digest(paste0(ts, privateKey, publicKey), algo="md5")
```

Server-side applications must pass two parameters in addition to the apikey parameter:

ts - a timestamp (or other long string which can change on a request-by-request basis)

hash - a md5 digest of the ts parameter, your private key and your public

key (e.g. md5(ts+privateKey+publicKey)
For example, a user with a public key of "1234" and a private key of "abcd" could construct a valid call as follows:

http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?ts=1&apikey=1234&hash=ffd275c5130566a2916217b101f26150 
(the hash value is the md5 digest of 1abcd1234)

Answer (score 6):

You need to have the following combination
**ts+ your private key+ your public key**

Please check the below example from MARVEL:

For example, a user with a **public key of "1234"** and a **private key of "abcd"** could construct a valid call as follows: http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?**ts=1**&apikey=1234&hash=ffd275c5130566a2916217b101f26150 (the hash value is the md5 digest of 1abcd1234)

**ts** -1
**private key**- abcd
**public key** - 1234

Answer (score 4):

The hash described in other answers is only when you're using your private key.

The public key can be used in the way you're attempting by adding a referrer:

```
curl --referer localhost http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/characters?apikey=f389fcb49ad574e10ca570867f4bfa43
```

I don't know `R` so a `curl` request will have to do.

In your developer account you can list the allowed referrers. I have localhost but your's can be whatever...